# Customers cant login to account 1.7.0.2 after SUPEE-8788 Patch

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, supee-8788

I had the same problem as [User login not work after SUPEE-8788 Patch](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141252/user-login-not-work-after-supee-8788-patch)

The suggested answers did not work for me, so I reversed the SUPEE-8788 Patch OK.

But still I cannot login to customer accounts.  Why would that be?

I am using /template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml as my login file.

I am also having an issue of not being able to login to admin after logging out. Again I have seen this linked to 8788 (php under 5.6 - I have 5.4).  But still have issue after revert.

what is going on?

EDIT - this is not a duplicate of a question that I specifically referenced in my question that the result did not work.  It is quite lazy to say this is a duplicate as if you read the quection you can see that answer has been considered and does not work. And I said I reverted the patch and still had a problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User login not work after SUPEE-8788 Patch](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141252/user-login-not-work-after-supee-8788-patch)

Comment: I clearly linked that question in my question, saying it did not work and still have the issue after removing 8788.  Clearly you did not read the question.  It was a PHP 5.4 issue

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara please read the questions before marking them as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Try to add that in your customer login form

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

Comment: I said in the question that was not a solution

Comment: Actually i faced issue on other question but it worked, thanks